# NginX no longer redirecting non-www to www after Ubunutu restart

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl

Ok, so I recently set up Ubuntu (node.js) w. Nginx and SSL (letsencrypt) on my server and got everything running perfectly.

I had 3 server{} blocks.

- One redirecting all non-www requests to www
- One redirecting all calls on port 80 to https://
- One setting a reverse proxy to serve SSL and node and what not.

Everything was working according as above, BUT, after restarting ubuntu only the 3rd one (serve SSL) is working, and it is now completely ignoring the 1st and 2nd one despite nginx running without errors (hence why the 3rd block works). So it no longer redirecting non-www to www and http to https, however, when I access directly from https it working perfectly. Not sure whats going on & why this happened after restart.

**Here is the code located in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:**

```
# Redirect non-www to www
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTP - redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
        # Enable HTTP/2
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:433 ssl http2;
        server_name www.mydomain.com;

        # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
        # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;      
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host @http_host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

Comment: I see that you have mistyped `443` as `433`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! However, I'm still having this issue..

Answer (score 2):

```
# Redirect non-www to www
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

You are missing `listen` and SSL certificate directives from this block. It should be like this:

```
# Redirect non-www to www
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Furthermore, in your main server block, you have:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:433 ssl http2;
```

You should have these:

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=yes;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I've changed these things, however, it still doesn't redirect domain.com or www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com  ... Or at least it doesn't seem like it in the browser. But when I run an SSL check on domain.com it says it has a certificate, but doesn't reflect that when typed into the browser window. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: So what exactly happens when you load `domain.com`?